# Python text Categorization using TFIDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, tf-idf, text-classification, document-classification

I have a dataset like below

```
**ID**        **Text**                                     **Category**
   1     jake loves me more than john loves me               Romance
   2     july likes me more than robert loves me             Friendship
   3     He likes videogames more than baseball              Interest
```

I would need to use the above as training data for my text categorization, and later when I pass a new sentence, that sentence would need to be classified as one category from the above categories provided in the table above.

To start with, I have performed the TFIDF (term frequency inverse document frequency) for the above dataset as below

```
mydoclist = []
#below im only taking my field 'Text' as input 
f = open('C:\sample4.csv', "r")
reader = csv.reader(f) 
for row in reader:   
    models.append(row)
f.close()

tf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda doc: doc,lowercase=False, analyzer='word',  min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english')
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(mydoclist)
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names()
tfs = tf.fit_transform(mydoclist)
#storing my tfidf matrix
import pickle
with open("x_result.pkl", 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tfidf_matrix, handle)
```

I would like to know how can I tag the categories from the above dataset with the tfidf matrix that I have calculated? Also, later how can I use the above data to categorize any new data?

Comment: You need to train a model. See the [Classification of text documents using sparse features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html) tutorial on the `sklearn` website.

Comment: Thanks for the input and for sharing the article. Presently im looking for very basic implementation where i would be able to use a train data from my CSV and i would like to know how can i train to categorize based on my existing categories

Answer (score 0):

You can use the libsvm with python.

1.The first thing to do is to represent your document by respecting the format of the file provided by libsvm.

2.Then, your read the data :

```
from libsvm import *
prob = svm_problem(your data…)
```

3.You set the svm parameters

```
param = svm_parameter(kernel_type …)
```

4.training  the model

```
m = svm_model(prob, param)
```

5.then you test the model for the new documents

```
m.predict(your new data...)
```